# How do I properly upgrade Wordpress's PHP within an OpenLiteSpeed GCP instance?

Tags: php

I have a Wordpress site running off of a GCP OpenLiteSpeed deployment running ubuntu 18.04.1 and PHP 7.0.33-13+bionic. Wordpress informed mePHP is in need of updating, but there are a couple of things are in my way in terms of understanding what to do bc PHP is not really in my knowledge set functionally:

1)I am confused about whether between the cyberpanel implementation and the OLS server and WordPress instance, there exists more than one application that can run their own PHP setup. My guess is that cyberpanel has its own and OLS and WP share one...

2)So is the PHP that needs to be upgraded a sole entity that openlitespeed server and WordPress require, so its just part of the stack?

Forgive my ignorance here; I feel like I've answered half of my questions...

The WordPress-linked GCP instructions are here: [Google Cloud App Engine PHP upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences)

Way too much of that is unfamiliar to me, and the last thing I want to do is lose my site again, especially because of recent GCP limitations on my account.

However, I did stumble on this info from OLS that sheds a little bit of light on the default install location but not how to install PHP: [default openlitespeed php settings](https://openlitespeed.org/kb/default-php-settings-for-openlitespeed/)

How should I best proceed? Or am I stuck with GCP instructions? Or more likely an out of date version until the next marketplace deployment...

Comment: Is there a WordPress-specific angle here? It sounds like this is just how to update PHP on GCP, so I don't understand the migration from SuperUser to here.

Comment: And it looks like the answer is just 'choose a base runtime with a later PHP version' - there are no changes needed to the WordPress code - but I don't know GCP. I guess back the whole site, files and database, up off GCP and give it a go? Or clone a new instance of your server temporarily to experiment with.

Comment: @Rup I'm confused also. If this update didn't have possible implications on an OLS server i know nothing of, and for which there is little to no support or documentation for, I wouldnt have come to the big boys table to ask.

Comment: I let the free credit creep on on me and suddenly im way in the whole so I can do very little within my acct. Im not sure exactly what you mean with up off GPC, but I will see if I can create an image of what I have before I try this out. Ill try your query thanks

Comment: Sorry, that was poorly written: I meant "backup the whole site".

Comment: @Rup Different angle required for suceess. Achieved

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Cyberpanel is in control of PHP assignments within this Google Cloud Platform Marketplace VM instance of Openlitespeed using WordPress and running Ubuntu 18.04.1.

Once logged in to Cyberpanel, hit Dashboard on the left-hand column. Click dashboard. PHP is among the selections. From there you select which version is most appropriate.

There is an extension the will indicate what most recent PHP version is suitable for each plugin. Choose carefully.